# How can I stream video to a browser using Java/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, video-streaming

We a have jboss server running and have a basic web setup using Spring but now I would like to stream video into the browser. I am trying to use [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/) but then I read on their website that you can't put it into an Applet or use it with java webstart, so I'm assuming that means I can stream to a browser, is this assumption correct?  If so does anyone else know any libraries or how I should go about doing this?  If you need any more info or have questions I'll be happy to answer although I'm very new to streaming video and relatively knew to Spring.

UPDATE:  So I'm able to generate a video using xuggle, and then I can embed that video in my html code... but I can't generate and stream at the same time.  Does anyone have any ideas how to make xuggle push date out to my tomcat server?

Comment: Have you considered just using the HTML5 video element in a web page?

Comment: I have not, to be honest I don't even know how that would work?

Comment: Are you doing Spring MVC? What is your web app doing? It must be outputting HTML somewhere right? Or is it a web service?

Comment: Yes I am using Spring MVC and right now all it's doing is displaying some jsp files that we made.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) media server.

Comment: Is there a .war file that I can plop into my jboss/tomcat server for red5?

Comment: Yes. See deployment documentation at http://code.google.com/p/red5/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing jsp, just have your code write out the [HTML 5 video element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video). That will provide basic video functionality. This will work in all HTML 5 compliant browsers as well as all mobile devices.

Comment: So I'm able to generate a video using xuggle, and then I can embed that video in my html code... but I can't generate and stream at the same time.